# Count of matching elements in a list and array

Tags: c#

I have a list and an array. I want to find out the number/count of elements in the array that match those in the list

```
List<int> list = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2 };
```

Since the two matching elements are 1 and 2, I am expecting a result of count 2. 
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You want the `Count` of the `Intersect`ion.

Comment: @user2864740 that should be an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a little Linq with the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
var count = array.Count(list.Contains);
```

Or if you know that there are no duplicate values in the the array, you can use the [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var count = array.Intersect(list).Count();
```

Comment: I know that there are no duplicates so the second option will work fine.

Comment: @user1527762 Well the second option is slightly faster, especially if there are many items in the list, so I'd go with that. Also, `array.Intersect(list)` and `list.Intersect(array)` will produce the same result, but one may be faster than the other, depending on the parameters. If this is a performance critical portion of code, you might want to do some benchmarking, but in general you should favor the solution which is the clearest and easiest to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
int matches = list.Intersect(array).Count();
```

Note that this will only work if the list and array only contain unique values.

Comment: Note that if array is `{ 1, 2, 2 }` there are 3 matching elements, but this will produce 2 as a result.